# two check boxes that are interdependent

Tags: jquery

i have two check boxes that when clicked individually perform there tasks but if both are clicked then there is an other task that should be perform but i am facing an issue.

when i click only 1st check box it should do this. and when i click only  2nd check box it should do this but when i click one and then other and both are checked now do this. i need to do this in jquery

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb6zm/)

```
if(checkbox1) is checkd 
{
   //do this
}

if(checkbox2) is checkd 
{
   //do this
}

if(both) are checked do this
```

here is the html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="kk" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="kk" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
var oneChecked = jQuery('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
var twoChecked = jQuery('#checkbox2').is(':checked');
if (oneChecked && twoChecked) {
    // both are checked
} else if (oneChecked) {
    // checkbox1 is checked
} else if (twoChecked) {
    // checkbox2 is checked
} else {
    // nothing is checked
}
```

Comment: Stashing the common objects before going in the loop is a good way +1

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($("#checkbox1 input:checked") && $("#checkbox2 input:checked")){
--

}
else if($("#checkbox1 input:checked"){
 ---
}

else if($("#checkbox2  input:checked"){
 ---
}else{
-------------nothing checked
}
```

Comment: Darn - you beat me by 2 seconds :p

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    // if both are checked
}
else if ($('#checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
    // if checkbox1 are checked
}
else if ($('#checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
    // if checkbox2 are checked
}
```